# What can I do to reduce the bootup time?

Tags: boot, 20.04, systemd

I've just installed ubuntu 20.04, but it boots up very slowly. Is there a way to reduce the bootup time?

Here is the output of my `systemd-analyze blame` command:

```
3min 2.442s snapd.seeded.service                                 
        46.016s plymouth-quit-wait.service                           
        10.521s NetworkManager-wait-online.service                   
         9.214s networkd-dispatcher.service                          
         8.859s dev-sda4.device                                      
         6.851s udisks2.service                                      
         4.945s accounts-daemon.service                              
         4.212s polkit.service                                       
         4.196s NetworkManager.service                               
         3.681s apparmor.service                                     
         3.557s avahi-daemon.service                                 
         3.555s bluetooth.service                                    
         3.293s grub-common.service                                  
         3.216s switcheroo-control.service                           
         3.082s grub-initrd-fallback.service                         
         3.037s systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service                       
         2.872s dev-loop0.device                                     
         2.834s systemd-logind.service                               
         2.833s thermald.service                                     
         2.830s wpa_supplicant.service                               
         2.455s snapd.service                                        
         2.364s secureboot-db.service                                
         2.171s fwupd.service
```